# Javascript Loop and Add Object

Tags: javascript

I have an API call that returns data. API might return 1 object or 2 objects within this data, I don't know ahead a time. So I have a foreach that loops thru however many I get, then I want to assign certain part of each object to a new object. `+=` operator in this case is not working at all, and when I do = it makes it equal to the last one only.

```
let customData = data.data;
let fullArray;
customData.forEach(element => {
   fullArray += JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element.customData));
});
console.log(fullArray);
```

What I get is this

```
undefined[object Object][object Object]
```

Comment: `let fullArray;` is `let fullArray = undefined` so you are doing `undefined` plus Object, which makes little sense that you are concatenating objects.

Comment: don't naively copy objects using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, a [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) function is superior to a forEach.

```
let data = { data: [{customData: 'A'}, {customData: 'B'}] };

let fullArray = data.data.map(element => element.customData);
console.log(fullArray);
```

Output:

```
["A", "B"]
```

Comment: Kaboom! This 1 liner does the job better than forEach + assignment.. `const fullArray = customData.map(element => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element.customData)) );` Thank you @patstuart!

Answer (score -1):

```js
let data = { data: [{customData: 'A'}, {customData: 'B'}] };

let customData = data.data;
let fullArray = [];
let fullArrayAsObject = {};
customData.map((element, index) => {
   fullArray.push(element.customData);
   fullArrayAsObject [index] = element.customData;
});
console.log(fullArray, fullArrayAsObject);
```

Comment: @Extelliqent added solution for Object as well, use whatever suits your need